# How to partition a combinational circuit into parts with equal delay?

Tags: circuit-design, synthesis

I have a huge combinational circuit with a large delay. I like to partition this design (based on delay) into smaller parts and later, convert it to a sequential pipelined circuit. Are any of the existing tools, such as Design Compiler, Quartus, Yosys, ABC, etc., capable of such partitioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a concept called **register retiming** (or **register balancing**). Most of the commercial tools have attributes and options for it.

When the option is set, synthesis tool can move registers (flip-flops and latches) forward/backward and tries to optimize timing and/or area.

If it is hard to pipeline a design (e.g. a multiplier) by RTL, all registers can be put consequtively at the inputs or outputs of the design. Fox example, in case 3 registers put at the output, the tool tries to partition the combinational logic into 4 equal parts. I guess, register duplication also should be enabled for better results.

I can give some command examples for Design Compiler. The following command enables retiming in `My_Multiplier`.

```
set_optimize_registers -design My_Multiplier
```

If timing is the main goal, `-minimum_period_only` option can be used.

```
set_optimize_registers -design My_Multiplier -minimum_period_only
```

There is also a global option (`-retime`), but I don't know whether it can break the functionality of feedback loops.

```
compile_ultra -retime
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. I didn't even think about retiming and the fact that I can put a few registers in the design and expect the tool to optimize them using retiming.